# Tibco Seg Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, solaris, coredump, tibco

I'm currently using a tibco rv message queue and I'm tracking a core dump into the libraries.  Has anyone seen this behavior before with Tibco?

Env:  Solaris 5.10

mdb output:

```
> ::stack
libtibrv.so`_tibrvPool_Reclaim+0x3d(3eb, 8187d98, 80ba310, fea6f924)
libtibrv.so`_tibrvQueue_DispatchEx+0x579(812a2c8, 0, 0, 1, 3)
libtibrv.so`_tibrvQueue_Dispatch+0x28(812a2c8, 0, 0, fedf54fb)
libtibrv.so`_tibrvEvm_TimerThread+0x6e(0, fee2d244, fea6ffb8, fee08a6e)
libtibrv.so`_tibrvPool_ThreadHook+0x21(fedf5468)
libtibrv.so`_tibrvThread_HookWrapper+0x24(8074848)
libc.so.1`_thr_setup+0x4e(febd0a00)
libc.so.1`_lwp_start(febd0a00, 0, 0, fea6fff8, fed192f0, febd0a00)
```

I'm guessing the Reclaim is causing some heap corruption but for the life of me I can't figure out how to work around it.

To further complicate matters this code is being ported from Sparc to Intel platforms but I *believe* I've traced down all the instances that need to be modified.

Comment: How do you reproduce the segfault?

Comment: It only occurs 1/day, it will run fine all day long and then coredump early in the morning.  Then it's fine, until the same time the next morning.

Comment: If it's at certain time of the day is probable that the issue has nothing to do with your program but with some task/cron job that the system is set to run at that hour.